# Как отсортировать новую таблицу по убыванию значений столбца?

Tags: python, сортировка

Не получается отсортировать новую таблицу по новому столбцу. Пробовал и `sort()`, и `sorted()`, и `lambda` – все время пишет разные ошибки.

Исходный код:

```
data = [
    ['Ухмыляюсь', 2.26, 1.02, 87.3],
    ['Сияю от радости', 19.1, 1.69, 150.0],
    ['Катаюсь от смеха', 25.6, 0.774, 0.0],
    ['Слёзы радости', 233.0, 7.31, 2270.0],
    ['Подмигиваю', 15.2, 2.36, 264.0],
    ['Счастлив', 22.7, 4.26, 565.0],
    ['Глаза-сердца', 64.6, 11.2, 834.0],
    ['Целую', 87.5, 5.13, 432.0],
    ['Задумчивость', 6.81, 0.636, 0.0],
    ['Равнодушие', 6.0, 0.236, 478.0],
    ['Солнечные очки', 4.72, 3.93, 198.0],
    ['Громко плачу', 24.7, 1.35, 654.0],
    ['След от поцелуя', 21.7, 2.87, 98.7],
    ['Два сердца', 10.0, 5.69, 445.0],
    ['Сердце', 118.0, 26.0, 1080.0],
    ['Червы', 3.31, 1.82, 697.0],
    ['Класс', 23.1, 3.75, 227.0],
    ['Пожимаю плечами', 1.74, 0.11, 0.0],
    ['Огонь', 4.5, 2.49, 150.0],
    ['Переработка', 0.0333, 0.056, 932.0]
]

print('Название эмодзи  | Суммарное использование, млн')
print('-----------------------------------------------')
for i in data[:5]:
    sum = i[1] + i[2] + i[3]
    i.append(sum)
    print('{: <16} | {: >28.2f}'.format(i[0], i[4]))
```

Выводит:

```
Название эмодзи  | Суммарное использование, млн
-----------------------------------------------
Ухмыляюсь        |                        90.58
Сияю от радости  |                       170.79
Катаюсь от смеха |                        26.37
Слёзы радости    |                      2510.31
Подмигиваю       |                       281.56
```

Требуют использовать только `sort()`, но перепробовал кучу вариантов, не получилось и отчаялся.

---

PS Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960389/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-python/960390#comment1606366_960390):
необходимо отсортировать по убыванию значений столбца "Суммарное использование" из таблички, что код выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Изначально была ошибка в выводе: надо было выводить пять максимальных значений, а выводились просто первые пять.
2. Помогло так:

```
for i in data:
    sum = i[1] + i[2] + i[3]
    i.append(sum)

data.sort(key = lambda i: i[4], reverse = True)

print('Название эмодзи  | Суммарное использование, млн')
print('-----------------------------------------------')

for j in range(len(data[:5])):
    print ('{: <16} | {: >28.2f}'.format(data[j][0], data[j][4]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from tabulate import tabulate

new = [[x[0], sum(x[1:])] for x in data]
res = nlargest(5, new, key=lambda x: x[1])

headers = ['Название эмодзи', 'Суммарное использование, млн']
tab = tabulate(res, headers=headers, tablefmt='grid')
print(tab)
```

результат:

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
| Название эмодзи   |   Суммарное использование, млн |
+===================+================================+
| Слёзы радости     |                       2510.31  |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
| Сердце            |                       1224     |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
| Переработка       |                        932.089 |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
| Глаза-сердца      |                        909.8   |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
| Червы             |                        702.13  |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
```

---

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

df = (pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Название эмодзи','val1','val2','val3'])
res = df.set_index('Название эмодзи')
        .sum(axis=1)
        .nlargest(5)
        .to_frame(name='Суммарное использование, млн')
        .reset_index())
print(res)
```

результат:

```
  Название эмодзи  Суммарное использование, млн
0   Слёзы радости                     2510.3100
1          Сердце                     1224.0000
2     Переработка                      932.0893
3    Глаза-сердца                      909.8000
4           Червы                      702.1300
```

Comment: спасибо за комментарий! Не совсем так – необходимо отсортировать по убыванию значений столбца "Суммарное использование" из таблички, что код выводит. Вот с этим засада.

Comment: @lulzseq, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)